# How can i pass item position from onItemLongClick to another class?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, onitemlongclicklistener

My question is : how can i pass item position to another class. Please see my attached code.

When i press positive button inside AlertDialog,i go to the HandleAlertDialog class , and there i delete Name by id(in database i have two variables : id and name).

I don't know how to pass id from item position to sqhelper.deleteNameByNumber(**id**) in HandleAlertDialog class.

Thank you for your help.

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
            .setMessage("Choose one of the options")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new HandleAlertDialog())
            .setNeutralButton("No",new HandleAlertDialog())
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create();
        dialog.show();
        return false;
      }

    public  class  HandleAlertDialog implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which==-1){
                sqhelper.deleteNameByNumber(**???**);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `id` attribute in `HandleAlertDialog` class (I assume this is a `String` for my example):

```
public  class  HandleAlertDialog implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    private String id;

    public HandleAlertDialog(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (which==-1){
            sqhelper.deleteNameByNumber(id);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it in your `onItemLongClick`:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    // Retrieve id here (based on view, position ?)
    String id = "THIS IS YOUR ID";
    HandleAlertDialog handleAlertDialog = new HandleAlertDialog(id);

    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
        .setMessage("Choose one of the options")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", handleAlertDialog)
        .setNeutralButton("No", handleAlertDialog)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .create();
    dialog.show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How can i retrieve id from item position? i have class Name with two variables(id, name).

Comment: Use item position to get `Name`object from the list you use to display them, I can't help more because I don't have Name and listview adapter

Answer (score 0):

Just pass id in the constructor.

```
public boolean onItemLongClick (AdapterView parent, View view,int position, final long id){
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

                .setMessage("Choose one of the options")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new HandleAlertDialog(id))
                .setNeutralButton("No", new HandleAlertDialog(id))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();
        dialog.show();

        return false;
    }
```

Add the Constructor.

```
public  class  HandleAlertDialog implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener
{
    long id;

    public HandleAlertDialog(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (which==-1){
            sqhelper.deleteNameByNumber(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Just let me know if it is not clear.